# How go to the Fragment page from activity using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, fragment, require

This is my Activity function that the startActivity(i) unable go to the Fragment page after scanning a barcode, I have try that it can go to activity page and show the code successful but I need it go to Fragment page.

```
barcodeDetector.setProcessor(object : Detector.Processor<Barcode> {

        override fun release() {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Scanner has been closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }

        override fun receiveDetections(detections: Detector.Detections<Barcode>) {
            val barcodes = detections.detectedItems
            if (barcodes.size() == 1) {
                scannedValue = barcodes.valueAt(0).rawValue
                runOnUiThread {
                    cameraSource.stop()
                    Toast.makeText(this@InsertStockInActivity, scannedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val i = Intent(this@InsertStockInActivity, comFragment::class.java)
                    .putExtra("cameraSource", scannedValue)
                    startActivity(i)
                    finish()
                }
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@InsertStockInActivity, "value- else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }

    })
```

This is my Fragment page. do I write anything wrong?

```
 class comFragment : Fragment() {
       private lateinit var binding: FragmentComBinding
       private val nav by lazy { findNavController() }

       private val vm: StockInViewModel by activityViewModels()

       private val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy '-' hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault())

       override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
       binding = FragmentComBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
       //binding.btnScanBarcode.setOnClickListener{ nav.navigate(R.id.insertStockInActivity) }

       val value = requireActivity().intent.getStringExtra("cameraSource")
       binding.edtId.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.value)

       return binding.root
   }
```

}

Comment: You don't use `Intent` to navigate to fragment . Please  read the basics . follow some tutorial on Fragment if you will . It will help u better understand how fragment navigation works ..

Comment: Use fragment transation to go to the fragment and its not working until you dont have frame layout in your activity or you can use fragment navigation compnent as well

Answer (score 0):

You use intent to navigate to `Activity` not to `Fragment`.

You can:

1. Use [fragment transactions](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions) to navigate to new `Fragment` in your current `Activity`
2. Use intent to navigate to new `Activity` and in your new `Activity` use [fragment transactions](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions) to your `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that extends FragmentActivity and start your fragment there:

```
public class MyFragmentActivity extends YourActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState == null){
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(android.R.id.content, new MyFragment ()).commit();}
        }
    }
```

then fragment constructor:

```
public MyFragment() {
}
```

then from your calling activity, start your fragment activity in the normal way

```
   Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, MyFragment.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I using kotlin, need to create activity or fragment page ?